# adding CONFIG_PARROT while compiling arm Linux Kernel 2.6.37

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, embedded, kernel-module, parrot

I will like to know how do the kernel builder to compile parrot modules while compiling the kernel.

I saw a config file for 2.6.32 that has the `CONFIG_PARROT` modules to yes. And I know where this modules files are stored on the kernel 2.6.32 source. I want a 2.6.37 kernel builder to make this parrot modules and add them to the kernel so I can use them on a VM.

Beside adding the path to the drivers source on the Makefile and setting the `CONFIG_PARROT` lines to the .config file of the kernel, is there something else to do?

Comment: Not sure why you would have to add the path.  Are you building from within the kernel tree?  One quick and easy way to be sure that your CONFIG_x option is set is to put an intentional error in between the #ifdef CONFIG_x and try to compile.  If it catches the error, then it is set.  Remove the error and recompile.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and give a feedback

Comment: *"setting the CONFIG_PARROT lines to the .config file of the kernel"* -- manual editing of the `.config` file (if that is actually what you mean) is dangerous.  Using `menuconfig` is always preferred since that will check for configuration dependencies.

Comment: yes I mean to manualy edit the .config. I tryed menuconfig but I could not find where to enable the parrot config on the 2.6.37 that I want to build. In 2.6.32 this CONFIG_PARROT modules are set to =y.   .

Comment: I grep'd a linux 3.0 source tree, and found zero instances of CONFIG_PARROT (and only some copyright stuff for the word "parrot".  In other words this "Parrot" code you want to build is not in the mainline source.  You probably have to manually install the project package obtained from ??? (sourceforge?)  *"And I know where this modules files are stored"*  --  What directory is this, and what are the filenames?

Comment: This are the configs that Im tying to add :
#
# Parrot drivers
#
CONFIG_PARROT_GPIO=y
# CONFIG_PARROT_PWM is not set
# CONFIG_PARROT_DUMMY_SMSC43340_USB is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP34XX=y
CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP3430=y
CONFIG_ARCH_OMAP_PARROT=y
CONFIG_OMAP_PACKAGE_CBP=y

Comment: the source for those modules are under /linux/drivers/parrot on the 2.6.32 version that I have. now I want those modules to be on a mainline 2.6.37. You said that I should manualy add those packages. But How do I do that on embeded linux?

Comment: *"now I want those modules to be on a mainline 2.6.37."* -- Code modules are usually submitted by the author for inclusion in the mainline kernel tree.  Or are you using the word "mainline" w/o knowing what it means? *"How do I do that on embeded linux?"* -- You wrote that you were "compiling"; an "embeded"[sic] target is irrelevant.  The drivers from a vendor are typically installed by a **patch file**.  Look for a patch or a `.diff` file in that 2.6.32 directory.  Or it might be archived as a `.tar` or even `.bz2`.  Search the web for OMAP development or this "Parrot" board or platform.